# How can we fit the contents of WebBrowserControl exactly into the size as the WebBrowserControls size

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I need the contents of the Web Browser Control to exactly fit into the Web Browser Controls size.
I'm assigning an html file as input to the Web Browser Control as shown below

```
string openHTMLTag = @"<html><body>";
string bodyHTMLFormat= @"<table><tr><td>Hi</td></tr></table>";
string closeHTMLTag = @"</body></html>";
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", openHTMLTag, bodyHTMLFormat, closeHTMLTag);
```

I wanted the contents of the WebBrowser1 to fit inside it.
Even if i change the size of the WebBrowser1 it must automatically fit into it.

Could anyone please help me in this.

Comment: string bodyHTMLFormat= @"<table width="100%"><tr><td>Hi</td></tr></table>";

Comment: Width is fine, But height is not getting fitted. There it is creating vertical scrollbars. I don't want Scroll bars. It should get fitted into the height of the WebBrowser.